# Find name of the value which is in '.csv' fomat in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with different extension's values, Now i want check whether `'.csv'` is IN this Array or not . If it is then whats the name.

```
    Ex: -  Array
(
    [0] => xyz.mp4
    [1] => bulk_sample.csv
    [2] => abc.avi
    [3] => pqr.3gp

)
```

Here `'abc.csv'` is available in array. and name should be in `$name='abc.csv';`

Comment: What do you have so far and how is it failing?

Answer (score 1):

Simple *"one-line"* solution using `preg_grep` function:

```
$names = preg_grep("/\.csv$/i", $val);
print_r($names);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [3] => abc.csv
)
```

**Note**, that hypothetically there could be multiple `.csv` items

Comment: @Divakarcool, so? My solution works fine with a given array and your notation *name should be in $name='abc.csv'*

Comment: i have tried but not working

Comment: Yes It is working , Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

In this foreach loop is checking for sub string which is .csv for all elements in array.

```
<?php
$array =array('test.mp4','abc.avi','xyz.3gp','abc.csv');
$flag=false;
$filename="";
foreach($array as $check) {
    $place = strpos($check, ".csv");
    if ($place>0) {
        $flag=true;
        $filename=$check;
        break;
    } else {
        $flag=false;
    }
}

if($flag){

    echo "File Name:".$filename;
}else{
echo "not found any .csv in array"."<br>";
}

?>
```

Note: it will return first found name with .csv extension.

Comment: Actually my array is in 
[0] => xyz.mp4
[1] => bulk_sample.csv
[2] => abc.mp4
[3] => jkl.3gp

Comment: Thanks its working..